# I have a list of 15 to 30 coordinates. Given any X,Y coordinates, what is the way to find the closest coordinates on the list from front end side?

Tags: angularjs, google-api

I have a list of more than 20 latitude and longitude coordinates. Given any X,Y coordinates, then what is the way to find the closest coordinates on the list from front end side?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried and describe any issues.

Comment: I am trying to implement delivery location functionality for my project using google map apis, in which i have list of 15 outlet/store coordinates. Using google places search i get entered location coordinates. then my goal is to find the any  outlet/store can deliver product in entered location ,each outlet having 3 km radius area in which they can be deliver their product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the distance between any two points as a line. The length of this line can be found using the distance formula:

[image: formula]

Here x2 and x1 are the latitudes and y1 and y2 are the longitude of the two locations.

You can iterate through the list and find the shortest one to find the closest location.